# AWS Sagemaker does not update the package

Tags: python, conda, amazon-sagemaker

AWS Sagemaker's notebook comes with Scikit-Learn version 0.19.1

I would like to use version 0.20.2. To avoid updating it every time in the notebook code, I tried using the lifecycle configurations. I created one with the following code :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/conda install scikit-learn -y
```

When I run the attached notebook instance and go to the terminal, the version of scikit-learn found with `conda list` is correct (0.20.2). But when I run a notebook and import sklearn, the version is still 0.19.2.

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
```

Is there any virtual environment on the SageMaker instances where I should install the package ? How can I fix my notebook lifecycle configuration ?

Comment: hey, did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conda update does not refer to a specific virtualenv, while your notebook probably does. Therefore you dont see an update on the notebook virtualenv.

Comment: And what is the solution?

Comment: conda install -n yourENVname somePackage

Comment: what is this 'yourENVname' refers to?

Comment: There's multiple conda environments available, you need to be explicit which environment your addressing.

Comment: @GiliNachum Sorry, your answer isn't helpful. How can a user find out, if and which environment is used?