# Upgrade python modules in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I just created an EC2 instance (in SageMaker) and ran the following commands in Jupyter Lab.

```py
import fsspec
print(fsspec.__version__)
```

0.6.2

---

But I need version 0.8.4, so I did:

```py
!pip install fsspec==0.8.4
```

Requirement already satisfied: fsspec==0.8.4 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.8.4)

---

This is confusing. So I did one more time:

```py
import fsspec
print(fsspec.__version__)
```

Result: 0.6.2

---

So, in this case I have both versions installed, but I need to use 0.8.4. How do I make Jupyter Lab use the version I want? (0.8.4)

Additionally, I also tried `!pip install tqdm==4.51`, in this case, the new version 4.51 actually installed, but when I go ahead and do `print(tqdm.__version__)`, I still get the old version 4.42. Same problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the jupyter perhaps running on a different virtualenv/using a different python interpreter?

Comment: How could I check this?

Comment: I see now that you're using anaconda, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184145/aws-sagemaker-does-not-update-the-package)